# Getting data for Enhanced Profiles via API query

Tags: rest-api, query, documentation

First of all, I want to say I'm not a Salesforce user, so I apologize if I misunderstand any of the basic concepts of this system.

I'm writing an integration with the Salesforce API. I have been asked to make a query to the Enhanced Profiles table, but I don't really understand if this is really a table, or where do I find the fields in it.

I need to get a list of Enhanced Profiles and their data. Is this possible using a SOQL query? Any documentation pages I could consult?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is a Profile object but there is no "Enhanced Profile" object, so they'll need to clarify that.  For documentation, see the [main site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "Enhanced Profile" object, only a Profile object.  Perhaps they are referring to the "Enhanced Profile User Interface" setting in Salesforce, where "enhanced" refers to the UI, not the object.

For complete documentation, see the [developer documentation page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs) which includes an object reference guide and SOQL reference guide.

Comment: Thank you very much. Perhaps what they need is UserRole, I will ask them about it. Thanks again!